# How to Use Ionic Capacitor Live Reload [Ionic-Angular]

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using VSCode to create/edit my Ionic app.  To view my app in the Android emulator I run the following in a terminal window:

```
ionic capacitor run android --livereload-url=http://localhost:8100
```

This starts Android Studio with no problems.  I then run my code, which starts the emulator - again, no problem.  I am able to use the emulator to test my app.

But, after editing the code in VSCode, how do I get the emulator to reload with the new code?  I've tried clicking the "Apply Changes and Restart Activity" icon in the menu bar.  I've also tried the "Apply Code Changes" menu bar icon.  Both will reload the app.  But, I do not see any of my changes.

What am I missing?

Comment: It should automatically compile on save, like if you were doing an ionic serve on your device, can't you see if the project is compiling?

Comment: try this `https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/guides/live-reload`

Comment: @ShinichiKudo, it does not auto compile on save.  The only thing I've figured out to this point is the run

`ionic capacitor sync android`
Then open the Android Studio window and run "Apply Changes and Restart Activity."  This works, but takes a lot of time and just seems impractical.

Comment: @RaviAshara, thank you for the link.  I've used there directions.  There is no change in the behavior - still no "livereload" on saves.